# Vue, sharing child components from one parent component to the other

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

> this is a question about best practices, in short: what is the best way to implement this function

I used the vue cli to create a project to train on. And so the normal template it provided me with was a side header thing with the content on the side, and so I made some modifications:

[image: preview of current situation]

`the issue is visualized down if the text explaination wasn't clear`
and so what I had in mind was to add a slot in the header "the left side" to add the adding button, and the button wouldn't need to be visible in the other tabs, like the help tab.

App.vue

```html
<template lang="pug">

TheHeader

routerView( v-slot="{ Component }" )
  transition( name='slide-fade' mode='out-in' )
    component( :is="Component" )


</template>
```

but here comes the issue, as you can see the tabs are in router views and the router view is beside the header component. the solution I had in mind was to:

1. add a list of strings in the App.vue with `["help", "course", ...]` in the script section
2. the strings are linked to what router is being used (not very sure how to do this but I guess I could do a v-model to the v-slot being used)
3. pass the string to the header component
4. include a v-if statement with every tab's little widget

but I felt like this alone will jank the code a lot and thought if maybe there was an easier way to pass an entire component from one child to another it would be great. if there isn't I'd just like to know if it's the best practice I could do and proceed with this solution

issue visualization:
[image: issue visualization]

wanted behavior mock-up:
[image: Final wanted behavior mock-up]

Comment: if anyone would like a hands-on the code to try to fix it, the code is open source https://github.com/NyllRE/vue3-mastering

Comment: Not sure if I've got the problem correctly. But if you need to have `+` outside route view \ in a route, it can be solved by having multiple route views per route.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to use the Built In `<Teleport>` Vue component. this way I just type `<Teleport to="...">` and it will go where I want